# Android JNI NoSuchMethodError : method not found in class Ljava/lang/Class

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am working on Android JNI, In which I am trying to call a Java method from JNI, but getting following error:

> *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='callmeback' signature='(I)V' in class Ljava/lang/Class;*

here is my code snippet.

**Java code-**

```
private void callmeback(int radius) 
{
Log.d("native", "hieee" + radius);
}
```

**Native code -**

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_nativeaudio_NativeAudio_selectClip(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,
            jint count)
    {
    ...........
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callmeback", "(I)V");
    if (mid == 0) {
        return;
    }
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid, count);
    return JNI_TRUE;
    }
```

One more thing, I have written this method in NativeAudio class then, why it is giving error as method not found in Ljava/lang/Class.
Am I missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `selectClip()` method in your Java code? In particular, did you declare it "static"?

Comment: Hi, this is how I am calling selectClip(), I have not declared it static.
((Button) findViewById(R.id.hello)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
      selectClip(1);
     }
    });

Comment: That's not the declaration, that's the call. Somewhere in your Java code you have to declare the method with the `native` keyword. Also, when adding additional bits of code, it's much easier to read if you edit it into the question rather than pasting it into a comment.